# ASP MVC 5 Route Mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Insides my views folder I have a 'User' folder, this does not contain a corresponding view, but contains sub folders which will contain a view.

Example:

```
User
 Create
   create.cshtml
 Edit
   edit.cshtml
```

I then have one controller, currently only with one action for create:

```
public ActionResult Create() {
    return View("Create/Create");
}
```

So to hit that action I go to `user/create`, and that returns the view fine.

The problem comes from when I am trying to link to that view in an `<a>` tag using `Url.RouteUrl`. It errors and says:

> A route named 'user/create' could not be found in the route collection

But to me, it matches the default route in the route config: `controller/action`.

Here is my RouteConfig:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  // Turn on attribute routing in the controllers
  routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new {
      controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
  );
}
```

So why do I need to define a custom route for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to define a custom route for it, but you need to follow the convention for your folders. Put the create.cshtml and edit.cshtml views directly inside the User folder, and delete the Create and Edit subfolders, you don't need them.

Now, in the controller, you can simply use:

```
public ActionResult Create() {
    return View();
}
```

It knows what to look for and where to find it, so it will pick your User/create.cshtml view successfully. However, we usually pass a model to our views. In such a view like the Create, the model is used to build all the controls (textboxes, labels, etc):

```
public ActionResult Create() {
    var model = new UserViewMode();
    return View(model);
}
```